# iPhone time did not update with daylight savings time (3/8/2020)

Tags: iphone, network, time, timezone

I spent a long time with Apple Support today and I still don't have a resolution to this issue.  They left it with the suggestion that I reset my network settings.  I could do that, but then I would spend the next week redoing all my settings (which I've done multiple times before - and had issues recur, so frankly I'd rather just set the time manually for awhile and see if I can figure out the root cause).

**Problem**:

Neither my wife's nor my iPhone updated with daylight savings time today (which should have happened at 2am (3/8/2020).  So our phones (when "set automatically") are an hour behind.

**My iPhone specs**:

- 6S
- iOS 13.3.1
- Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Set Automatically = On
- Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Time Zone

  - Initially = New York *which is correct*
  - Now (with set automatically = on) = Etc/GMT+5
  - Now (with set automatically = off) = spinning wheel that never ends (but I can tap it and select "New York" and the default time it shows me after that is **correct**)
- Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> System Services -> Setting Time Zone = on

**My wife's iPhone specs**:

- 6S
- iOS 12.x
- Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Set Automatically = On
- I can get more info if requested

**Things I tried** (in this order):

1. Turned airplane mode on and off
2. Turned off WiFi and tried cycling "set Automatically" using cell data connection
3. Updated from 13.3 to 13.3.1
4. Hard reset phone (by holding the power & home button)
5. Cycled the "Setting Time Zone" setting

**Question**:

Without resetting all my network settings, how can I have the date and time "set automatically" and show the correct time (because it's currently 1 hour behind).

**Possibly related**:

I have a hunch that this is all related to a series of network issues that started when I implemented a simple new DHCP reservation on my Airport Extreme, but I don't want to muddy this issue, so I'll keep it focussed and ignore potentially unrelated network symptoms - unless anyone asks.

Also, my mom has an iPhone 11 and hers showed an hour behind until just after 7 AM.  They saw it updated within a minute of it correcting itself.  They are also on NY time.

Comment: This is typically not done via your WiFi connection, but via your *carrier.*  This is how even "dumb phones" were able to have their time synced.  I would start looking in that direction - who's your carrier?  Contact them to ensure that your network (not your Wifi, but your *cellular network*) settings are correct?

Comment: Ok. Good tip. All 3 of us (me, wife, and mom) have sprint. What’s more is, my wife and I have our own personal “cell tower” (though it’s specifically for voice calls I think). It’s called an Air Rave. But we’ve had it for years and have been through numerous DST boundaries with no issue.

Comment: From what I understand, this is SprintPCS over Internet - all the more reason to contact them because when it comes to sync'ing time over the Internet, it's typically done with [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).  As far as I can tell, there's no NTP library within iOS.

Comment: Well, like I said, we’ve been using it for years, probably around 5 or so years and we’ve had sprint the entire time. We haven’t had this problem before, so I believe it either has worked or not interfered in the past. I know it’s still operating at least for voice. I made a call this evening and when it’s working, I hear 3 tones before it starts ringing and the call quality was good. My mom doesn’t have an air rave though and her phone updated, albeit late.

Comment: Just because your phone works (you can make calls) doesn't mean that the time synch worked.  You're looking for an "Apple" solution when it's a "Sprint" problem.  The fact that your  Mom's phone updated *late* points you to this.

Comment: I don’t disagree with you. It’s just that I thought you were claiming that our phones *could not* update for DST changes with the air rave in play and I was stating that it seems to have updated with DST changes in the past and that it otherwise seems to be functioning normally. If I misunderstood, I apologize. I appreciate your insights into this issue.

Comment: I'm not saying that at all!  I'm saying that there's something "up" with Sprint's network - the Airave may not have been updated (by Sprint) properly, their network may be congested with traffic (as evidenced by your Mom's issue) a combination of both or something else altogether.  Back in the day, AT&T had an issue with DST and I fixed it by accident when I flew into and landed in a different time zone.  It "forced" an update so to speak.  But, it *was* a carrier issue in the end.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I don’t claim to know well the ins and outs of the airave, but I did have the impression it didn’t do anything related to data (although I admit, I don’t know if that’s what is used for syncing the time). Do you think it would be worth a try to disconnect the airave and see if the time syncs properly? We do get a weak signal without it - just choppy and calls drop.